# How to convert object to array and set value in to selectfield in sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Actually I get country from server: England, So How to set selectfield that england. I could not set in select field.

In other textfield, i manage like this;

```
Ext.getCmp('email').setValue(email);
```

**But why not in selectfield, work?**

I have very in sencha. Now i want to convert array.

```
var testcountry=  Ext.create('Test.store.CountryList');
console.log("Length of Country==="+testcountry.getCount());
console.log("Country==="+testcountry);

for (var i = 0 ; i < testcountry.getCount() ; i ++){
    console.log("Country Value--"+testcountry.getAt(i).data.country);
}
```

Here **console.log("Country Value--"+testcountry.getAt(i).data.country);**

all country print in console undefined.

In Model:

```
Ext.define('Test.model.countryList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'widget.countrylist', 
    config: {
        fields: ['text']
    }
});
```

In Store:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.countryList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
    storeId: 'countryList',
    model: 'Test.model.countryList',
    data: [
    { text: ''},
    { text: 'Japan'},
    { text: 'India'},
    { text: 'Spain'},
    { text: 'Australia'},
    { text: 'Sudan'},
    { text: 'Brazil'},
    { text: 'Mexico'},
    { text: 'England'},
    { text: 'Chaina'},
   ]
}
});
```

In Console like this:

```
Length of Country===9 
Country===[object Object] 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined 
Country Value--undefined
```

How do i print all countries.

Comment: post your selectfield code

Answer (score 0):

Your **For** loop snippet should simply be like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < testcountry.getCount() ; i ++){
    console.log("Country Value--"+testcountry.getAt(i).getData().text);
}
```

You need to mention the exact field name that you are using in the model.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to put to populate this on a Selectfield, you will do like this:

```
{
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Select Country',
                        store: 'countryList'
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that, Now, How to put that selected country like England in selectfield . I did not get any idea, how to set england in select field.

Comment: Create a selectfield and then set the store to that selectfield. If you are using Sencha Architect, just drag the select field --> Go to Config panel --> Select Store property --> Choose the store name (in your case, it should be countryList). Look at the updated answer.